# Android - multiple Gson libs in different SDKs

Tags: java, android, reflection, sdk

We are using couple of SDKs with our app and some of them have Google Gson library but in different package e.g. thirdpartylib.gson.Gson, thirdpartylibsecond.gson.Gson, .... We use com.google.gson.* package as well but the thing is: Is there any way how to use one of the Gson from other SDKs instead of ours? The main reason is to reduce number of method IDs.

We are thinking about using reflection something like:

1) Create our stub class for Gson and use it everywhere in our app -> GsonStub.

2) Check if any other Gson is available: 
`Class cl = Class.forName('<specific-gson>')`

3) and then use method delegation in our GsonStub: 
`cl.getDeclaredMethod()`

But problem is that another our 3rd party library takes com.google.gson.Gson as parameter. Moreover, each call of Gson method in this implementation could cost us extra resources because of reflection.

Has anyone got experience with this 'issue'? It seems ineffective to have linked number of same Gson libs each with around 900 method IDs.

Comment: @Selvin thanks for reply, but I am not sure how that could help. In addition, we are 3rd party lib as well which means that our app/lib can someone integrate but he already can have other SDKs with Gsons. So I would like to check classpath if there are other impl of Gsons and use one of them.

Comment: i was thinkig about rename/repackage `xxxx.gson.*` to `com.google.gson.*` inside both 3rd party libraries with(jarjar) and remove implementation from there (gradle ? dependecies exclude?) ... then compile against new dependecies ... if you are lucky and versions of used gson libraries are compatible

Comment: yes, that would be nice to do that before 'release', but unfortunately as I mentioned, I need to do this at runtime (or pick one of the Gson instance at runtime). Next thing is that Gsons versions could be slightly different (depends on 3rd party SDK's Gson lib).